# How setup samba share only readable by a certain domain group?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, file-sharing

I'm using Ubuntu Server 12.04 connected to an active directory by Likewise open. I want to be able to share my files with others in the same domain group. I've followed [this guide](http://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-ad-integration.html)  and also uncommented the [homes] section in `smb.conf` file and created a new share with read permission for group members. I have only managed to share files when allowing guests, otherwise I only get an authentication pop-up, that is unable to actually authenticate with my credentials (my domain user, used to login on both Windows and Ubuntu). I've googled around and found lots of confusing information that either doesn't apply to Likewise open or simply doesn't work.  Surely I don't need to setup Samba as a Domain Controller to do this? I just want to setup an Ubuntu file server in a Windows domain. I can see the shares but when I double click I get a popup asking for user, domain and password, but none is accepted. I've tried to map the domain group to a Linux group but that didn't work either. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Am ok so.......

1. `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install samba`
2. `cd /etc/samba` then `sudo cp smb.conf smb.conf.back` (to backup...just in case :) )
3. `sudo nano smb.conf`, yes as the guide says go to that line with `WORKGROUP =` and type the name of your workgroup, then go to the bottom of the page and add your shares as example:

`[ share name ]`

```
path = /home/user_name/Public  # or whatever.
guest ok = yes  # SPACE is important so don't do guestok=yes
read only = yes  # or "no"
```

save and exit

Then the service part:

```
sudo service smbd restart (restart the service)
sudo ufw allow samba  (tell the firewall to allow samba)
```

Comment: As I wrote in my question, it works when guest are allowed but I only want to allow access to members of a certain domain group. Sorry if I wasn't clear on this.